# Provisional, publication and continuation

Tags: provisional, continuation

Suppose one files a provisional that describes methods A and B, then publishes a paper describing methods A and B, then files a non-provisional that claims the benefit of the provisional and describes method A only, then more than a year after publishing the paper files a continuation of the non-provisional that describes method B and makes a claim related to method B.  Does the paper count as prior art against the continuation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain back through the first non-povisional to get benefit of the provisional.  But you *do* need to specify the chain of applications in the new application. The USPTO has a [summary of the rules for this here](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/dapp/opla/preognotice/benefitclaims.pdf).